# opamp circuit for amplify up from 1.1V to 5 V

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier, dds

I am doing a DDS　function generator with AD 9850  [image]

,because of the charactericts of DAC converter http://www.analog.com/static/imported-files/data_sheets/AD9850.pdf, page 9 figure 5, the output of amplitude of waveform is decresing when increasing frequency, due to my requirement of DDS function generator
 a) operate within range 0 to 40 MHZ with 5V amplitude

So any opamp circuit can be suggested? as I am newbie to opamp device.

Comment: Pick any 5v opamp, look at it's datasheet for typical circuits.

Comment: Wikipedia has a few different amplifier circuits:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operational_amplifier#Negative_feedback_applications
However, if you need 40 MHz, you need to make sure your op-amp is fast enough.

Also, what kind of signal are you generating? This chip can certainly generate a 40 MHz signal, but you won't have a lot of resolution (i.e. a 40 MHz sine wave should really have at minimium a 400 MHz DAC behind it.)

Comment: I think what a few people are missing is that you really need an AGC (automatic gain control) circuit to keep it constant over the voltage range. I was expecting to be able to find a suitable circuit pretty quickly but couldn't. Most were based on obsolete parts or had other problems.

Comment: I ended up using LM7171 opamp from TI, it has a big GBWP and huge current output. Achieving 40MHz is a bold goal. ACG is probably a way to go there, but I couldn't find quick and easy solution. Please share if you come up with one.

Comment: @PeterJ, ya, a AGC is needed for this circuit,but AGC I have googled it and found information on its,and it just too complicated,basically while reading the information I am lost,and some IC like CLC IC has obsolete.

Comment: @miceuz,may you share more information on the LM7171 ,how is the connection?as it is a SMD package,so do you have the problem on soldering?

Answer (score 2):

The problem you are seeing is "natural" for DACs - you are probably best advised to use a sinc-compensation filter like this: -

[image]

I took this circuit from a very good (and readable) article by [Maxim](http://www.maximintegrated.com/app-notes/index.mvp/id/3853) entitled "Equalizing Techniques Flatten DAC Frequency Response"

Comment: hi Andy aka, this article clear all the cloud of my question,thanks so much...and then post equalisation can solve my problem, then could you recommend the suitable ic for the post equalisation technique?

Comment: you need an opamp with bandwidth greater than the highest frequency you are trying to equalize, preferably twice as high. You probably need to run it from a 5v rail and ideally you should choose one with rail to rail input and output but how big is your signal and what power rails do you use.

Comment: my output signal from the sensor is sine waveform around 1.1V fro frequency below 10 MHz, <br/>Output Frequency  Amplitude of the Output waveform
10.006Hz 1.13V
100.01Hz 1.16V
1kHz 1.16V
10.002kHz 1.13V
100.01kHz 1.13V
1MHz 1.09V
10MHz 1.17V
20MHz 680mV
30.1MHz 350mV
40.0MHz 143mV
50.6MHz 88mV

Comment: above were some result I collected,any chip or ic can be suggested for me?thanks in advance =)

Comment: power rails? LT6202 is good for 5V rails.

Comment: how dO I determine the power rails for the device?

Comment: What power rails are you using for the DDS?

Comment: 5V voltage  for the DDS

Comment: Then use the 5V for the op-amp

Comment: The connection for the circuit is look like the figure above? and then how do I calculate the value of resistor and capacitor? erm, this circuit is just used to compensate the sinc effect right and it doesn't amplify the voltage ?

Comment: It doesn't amplify the voltage other than to give a boost to the higher frequencies. You could scale the values shown in the circuit to match the actual frequencies you are using. Remember, this question is not a tutorial about op-amps. If you don't understand what to do raise a new question.